# Xcode error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode4, clang, x86-64

I am writing a template matrix class for a school assignment. I have included the error as well as the source and header files below. I don't think anything is wrong with my code, I am pretty sure that for some reason xcode isn't recognizing the header and source file. The tempmlated matrix class is declared in Matrix.h, the function definitions are in Matrix.cpp, and the main routine is in main.cpp. I have included all three files as well as the full error message that Xcode gives me below. I've spent the last 2 days googling this error to no avail. I am very new to xcode so any help is really appreciated. If you need me to post more information, like my settings or anything else, don't hesitate to ask. Thanks
THE FULL ERROR IS:

```
Ld /Users/Mikey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hw3-glwfyunpxigvvpfacidnbejyprfa/Build/Products/Debug/hw3        normal x86_64
cd /Users/Mikey/Desktop/programming/PIC10B/hw3
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -   isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/Mikey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hw3-glwfyunpxigvvpfacidnbejyprfa/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/Mikey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hw3-glwfyunpxigvvpfacidnbejyprfa/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/Mikey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hw3-glwfyunpxigvvpfacidnbejyprfa/Build/Intermediates/hw3.build/Debug/hw3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/hw3.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -stdlib=libc++ -o /Users/Mikey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hw3-glwfyunpxigvvpfacidnbejyprfa/Build/Products/Debug/hw3

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"operator^(Matrix<double>, int)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"operator>>(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Matrix<double>&)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`



//main.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
int numberOfPlanets;
int steps;
string planet;
vector<string> planetNames;
Matrix<double> markovMatrix;
Matrix<double> stepMatrix;

cout<<"Please enter the number of Planets:";
cin>>numberOfPlanets;
cout<<"Please enter the names of the Planets:";
for(int i=0;i<numberOfPlanets;i++) {
    cin>>planet;
    planetNames.push_back(planet);
}

cout<<"How many steps will you take?";
cin>>steps;

cout<<"Please enter the "<<numberOfPlanets<<"X"<<numberOfPlanets<<" Markov Matrix:";
cin>>markovMatrix;

stepMatrix=markovMatrix^steps;

for(int i=0;i<numberOfPlanets;i++) {
    int maxEntry = stepMatrix.findMax(i);
    cout<<"After "<<steps<<" steps, from "<<planetNames[i]<<"you are most likely to end up at "      <<planetNames[maxEntry];
    cout<<endl;
}





return 0;

}


//Matrix.h
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

using namespace std;



template<typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int r, int c);
   ~Matrix();
    Matrix<T>(const Matrix<T>& right);
    Matrix<T>& operator=(const Matrix<T>& right);
    T& operator() (int i, int j);
    T operator() (int i, int j) const;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix<T>&right);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Matrix<T>& right);
    friend Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T> left, const Matrix<T> right);
    friend Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T> left, const Matrix<T> right);
    friend Matrix<T> operator^(const Matrix<T> right, int power);
    int findMax(int r) const;
private:
    int rows;
    int columns;
    T* elements;
};

#endif`




//Matrix.cpp
#include "Matrix.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
    Matrix<T>::Matrix() {
    rows = 0;
    columns = 0;
    elements = NULL;
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int r, int c) {
    rows = r;
    columns = c;
    elements = new T[rows*columns];
    for(int i=0;i<rows*columns;i++) {
    elements[i]=0;
    }
}  

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T>& right) {
    rows = right.rows;
    columns = right.columns;
    elements = new T[rows*columns];

    for(int i=0;i<rows*columns;i++)
    elements[i]=right.elements[i];

}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator=(const Matrix<T>& right) {
    if(this!=&right) {
        rows = right.rows;
        columns = right.columns;
        delete[] elements;
        for(int i=0;i<rows*columns;i++) {
            elements[i]=right.elements[i];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
T Matrix<T>::operator()(int i, int j) const {
    return elements[i*rows+j];
}

template<typename T>
T& Matrix<T>::operator()(int i, int j) {
    return elements[i*rows+j];
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& right, const Matrix<T> left) {
    Matrix<T> A(right.rows, right.columns);
    for(int i=0;i<A.rows;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<A.columns;j++) {
            A(i,j) = right(i,j)+left(i,j);
        }
    }

     return A;
 }

 template<typename T>
 Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>& right, const Matrix<T> left) {
    Matrix<T> A(left.rows, right.columns);
    for(int i=0;i<left.rows;i++) {
         for(int j=0;j<right.columns;j++) {
             for(int k=0;k<right.rows;k++) {
                A(i,j)+=left(i,k)*right(k,j);
            }
        }
    }

    return A;
}

 template<typename T>
 Matrix<T>::~Matrix() {
     delete[] elements;
 }

 template<typename T>
 Matrix<T> operator^(const Matrix<T>& right, int power) {
     Matrix<T> A = right;
     for(int i=1;i<power;i++)
        A=A*right;
     return A;
 }

template<typename T>
int Matrix<T>::findMax(int r) const {
     int maxColumnEntry = 0;
     T rowMax = elements[r*columns];
     for(int j=1;j<columns;j++) {
         if(elements[r*columns+j]>rowMax) {
             rowMax = elements[r*columns+j];
             maxColumnEntry = j;
         }
     }

     return maxColumnEntry;
 }

template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const Matrix<T>& right) {
    for(int i=0;i<right.rows*right.columns;i++) {
        out<<setw(10)<<right.elements[i]<<" ";
        if((i+1)%right.columns==0)
            out<<endl;
    }
    return out;
}

template<typename T>
istream& operator<<(istream& in, Matrix<T>& right) {
    for(int i=0;i<right.rows*right.columns;i++){
        in>>right.elements[i];
    }

    return in;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that your function signatures do not match: i.e., `operator^(const Matrix<T> right, int power)` in the class definition (where `const` does nothing BTW), versus: `operator^(const Matrix<T>& right, int power)` in the function template implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that. However, I'm still getting the same error

Comment: It's two months later - did you ever find a solution? I have exactly the same problem. xcode is failing to link. It compiles my code correctly, and the error goes away if I #include the cpp files as well (because it doesn't need to link as all the symbols are definied in the main.cpp file) but this is not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're compiling with the wrong lib. change your build settings to use: Compiler Default in the Apple LLVM Compiler settings maybe even libstdc++.

And:

Project -> Build Settings -> Find LLVM Compiler group -> C++ Standard Library

Comment: I had it set  to libc++ before. I tried both options, and I still got the same error

Comment: Ugh figured it'd be something simple. I'll boot up the macbook when I get back to my house and see if I can track it down.

Comment: Haha, I think you're right that it is simple just not sure what it is. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Holyprin, any luck figuring it out?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I can't seem to reproduce the problem at all. I can tell you it is a linker problem with a specific library, which is about all I can tell you. :-\ I also don't do a whole lot of C++ in a mac environment unless I need a specific C++ function in Objective-C projects. Sorry. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a C program or a C++?

If C++,  build with G++ or Xcode project TYPE = C++,  not C.